# R - reshaped data from wide to long format, now want to use created timevar as factor

Tags: r, reshape

I am working with longitudinal data and assess the utilization of a policy over 13 months. In oder to get some barplots with the different months on my x-axis, I converted my data from wide Format to Long Format.

So now, my dataset looks like this

```
id month hours
1   1     13
1   2     16
1   3     20
2   1     0
2   2     0
2   3     10
```

I thought, after reshaping I could easily use my newly created "month" variable as a factor and plot some graphs. 
 However, it does not work out and tells me it's a list or an atomic vector. Transforming it into a factor did not work out - I would desperately Need it as a factor.

Does anybody know how to turn it into a factor?

Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT.**

The OP's graph code was posted in a comment. Here it is.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = hours, y = month)) + geom_density() + labs(title = 'Distribution of hours')
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a plot that didn't work?

Comment: ggplot(data, aes(x = hours, y = month)) + 
  geom_density() + 
  labs(title = 'Distribution of hours') <br /> It then tells me: Error in eval(substitute(list(...)), `_data`, parent.frame()) : 
  object 'y' not found  <br /> But I swear y is in this dataframe ;)

Comment: I think you need to show us the structure of your data using "str(dataset)". It is possible that you messed something up in your data rearrangement, which is a common mistake, that can e.g. happen if you return you output from a lapply like "dataset$column <- lapply(1:10, as.character)".

Comment: If you feel you question was answered you should accept one of the two answers, such that the question is marked as answered ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be in the `aes`. `geom_density` only needs a `x` value, if you think about it a little, `y` doesn't make sense. You want the density of the `x` values, so on the vertical axis the values will be the values of that density, not some other values present in the dataset.

First, read in the data.

```
Indirekte_long <- read.table(text = "
id month hours
1   1     13
1   2     16
1   3     20
2   1     0
2   2     0
2   3     10
", header = TRUE)
```

Now graph it.

```
library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(Indirekte_long, aes(hours))
g + geom_density() + labs(title = 'Distribution of hours')
```

Comment: As in my code, to compare months, you would have to set that as color.

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt Yes, but the code posted by the OP in a comment, that I have included in the question, doesn't seem to need to compare months. Also, your second `ggplot` instruction gives a graph very similar to mine, there are no separate densities by month.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Loading ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

# Placing example in dataframe
data <- read.table(text = "
id month hours
1   1     13
1   2     16
1   3     20
2   1     0
2   2     0
2   3     10
", header = TRUE)

# Converting month to factor
data$month <- factor(data$month, levels = 1:12, labels = 1:12)

# Plotting grouping by id
ggplot(data, aes(x = month, y = hours, group = id, color = factor(id))) + geom_line()

# Plotting hour density by month
ggplot(data, aes(hours, color = month)) + geom_density()
```

[image]